# header, content y footer que ocupen una altura de 100vh y header y footer acomoden su altura a su contenido

Tags: html, css, div, footer

Tengo el siguiente código que consta de un header, un contenido (contenedorCentralModal) y un footer.

Lo que estoy buscando es que tanto el header como el footer tengan una altura, height, que dependa del contenido del elemento y que el contenido (contenedorCentralModal) tenga un height que sea el resto.

Pero a la vez, que en el contenido del contenido esté centrado tanto verticalmente como horizontalmente:

```
  #contenedorPrincipalModal{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
   
  }
  #headerModal{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;;
  }

  #footerModal{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #contenedorCentralModal{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
  }
```

Este es el código html

```
 <div id="contenedorPrincipalModal">
      <header id="headerModal">
        <IonIcon icon={close} onClick={() => props.onClose(null)} slot="right" id="flecha-cerrar">  </IonIcon>
      </header>
      <article>
        <div id="contenedorCentralModal">
            <img onClick={() => props.setDatosPersonales(true)} src={imagen} id="foto-usuario-grande"/>

            <IonList>
     
                <IonItem id="item-modal" button onClick={() => { props.setDatosPersonales(true)}}>
                        <IonLabel >DATOS PERSONALES</IonLabel>
                        <IonIcon className="iconosModal" icon={person} ></IonIcon>
                </IonItem>

                <IonItem id="item-modal" button onClick={() => { }}>
                        <IonLabel>MIS TICKETS</IonLabel>
                        <IonIcon className="iconosModal" icon={receipt} ></IonIcon>
                </IonItem>

                <IonItem id="item-modal" button onClick={() => { }}>
                        <IonLabel>PREGUNTAS</IonLabel>
                        <IonIcon className="iconosModal" icon={help} ></IonIcon>
                </IonItem>

                <IonItem id="item-modal" button onClick={() => { }}>
                        <IonLabel>SOPORTE</IonLabel>
                        <IonIcon className="iconosModal" icon={chatbubble} ></IonIcon>
                </IonItem>

            </IonList>  

        </div>
        </article>

        <footer id="footerModal">
            <button  onClick={() => { props.closeSesion () } } className="cerrarsesion" >CERRAR SESIÓN</button>
        </footer>
 </div>
```

El problema es que la antura de header, contenedorCentralModal y footer se dividen equitativamente el tamaño de contenedorPrincipalModal. Y lo que quiero es que la altura del header y footer sea del tamaño del contenido de estos.

Trabajo con porcentajes y no con pixeles porque las pantallas en los dispositivos es diferente. Tampoco agrego porcentajes de altura porque no sé siempre que se mostrará en el header y el footer, por eso lo seteo en 100% a todos.
Pero si al header y el footer le pongo auto, la suma de los 3 contenidos no sera 100h

```
  #contenedorPrincipalModal{
    /* height: 100%; */
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border:solid;
    border-color: red;
  }
  #headerModal{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border:solid;
    border-color: green;
  }

  #footerModal{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border:solid;
    border-color: blue;
  }

  #contenedorCentralModal{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
    border:solid;
    border-color: red;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa `flex-grow` para señalar cómo los hijos del contenedor principal deben repartirse el espacio sobrante. Acá el central tiene flex-grow:1, y los otros dos no lo declaran.

(le puse al principal 400px de altura mínima, eso se lo puedes quitar)

```css
#contenedorPrincipalModal {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height:400px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: solid;
  border-color: red;
}
#contenedorPrincipalModal > div {
  height: auto;
  border-style: solid;
  padding:0.5em;
  font-size:0.9em;
}

#headerModal {
  border-color: green;
}

#footerModal {
  text-align: center;
  border-color: blue;
}

#contenedorCentralModal {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-items:center;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedorPrincipalModal">
  <div id="headerModal">Modals focus the user’s attention exclusively on one task or piece of information via a window that sits on top of the page content.  </div>
  <div id="contenedorCentralModal">Modals are a variant of dialog used to present critical information or request user input needed to complete a user’s workflow. Modals interrupt a user’s workflow by design. When active, a user is blocked from the on-page content and cannot return to their previous workflow until the modal task is completed or the user dismisses the modal. While effective when used correctly, modals should be used sparingly to limit disruption to the user.


  </div>
  <div id="footerModal">Modal dialogs are commonly used for short and non-frequent tasks, such as editing or management tasks. If a user needs to repeatably preform a task, consider making the task do-able from the main page.
  </div>
</div>
```